# Having an issue with React SSR and hydrate, when the DOM is too similar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm having a small problem and hope that maybe here i could find a solution.

We have a website that we created with React, we use this package to do server side rendering, and throw the resulting files in S3.

https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin

Then we do ReactDom.hydrate, like

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDOM.hydrate(
        <BrowserRouter context={{}} initialEntries={['/']} initialIndex={0}>
            { renderRoutes(Routes) }
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
```

To attach event listeners, and change the content for logged in users, and the sort.

Normally everything is fine, but if the DOM on the SSR result and the new one is too similar it breaks. For example.

```
<nav>
    {!isLoggedin && <a href="/login">Login</a>}
    {isLoggedin && <a href="/options">Options</a>}
</nav>
```

In a particular case like this, isLoggedIn is always false on SSR, so the login button will render first. Then hydrate will change to display the options button; the options word appears but the href is still the same, which is bad.

I tried using the key attribute, or changing some other properties, they get ignored, but I haven't found a way to prevent that, apart from making the DOM different, but is not always possible, like in that menu example.

Any tips or pointers appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The program you mentioned is only about 200 lines of code, consider reading it: https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js also, it doesn't appear like "having the same dom" is an issue, since the code doesn't appear to have dom comparison routines at first glance, perhaps the problem is somewhere else, not "having the same dom".